# $getJSON not working - undefined is the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

Here is the JSON I am trying to parse

```
{"sites":{"1":{"id":1,"company":"facebook","username":"abc@gmail.com","hint":"mascot"}}}
```

Here is the javascript parsing it.  It was working then the structure of the JSON changed and I cannot for the life of me get it work.  The result is 'undefinedundefined' which means that it does not understand what username and hint are.  Any thoughts?

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/sites.json', 'limit=30', processWebsites);
        function processWebsites(data) {
        var infoHTML='';


        $.each(data, function(website, websiteDetails) {
        infoHTML+= websiteDetails.username
        infoHTML+= websiteDetails.hint;
        });

        $('#info').html(infoHTML);
        }
```

and finally the HTML

```
  <body>

      <div id = "info">

      </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: You seem to need `$.each(data.sites, ...)`.

Comment: follow up question - is there a way to add a line break after each line of JSON.  I now have 2 rows of JSON and it is all together on one line.  Does the </br> go in the js code in the .each of the infoHTML below?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed a .sites after data.  this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe felix is correct above. If you just console this, you'll get the value you need.
update: add your breaks

```
var infoHTML = [];
var data = {"sites":{"1":{"id":1,"company":"facebook","username":"abc@gmail.com","hint":"mascot"}}};

jQuery.each(data.sites, function(){
  infoHTML.push(this.username + '<br>' + this.hint);
});
```

If you happen to get more than one grouping, then just join them with 2 br's if you want some seperation.

```
$('#info').html(infoHTML.join('<br><br>'));
```

I am sure there are much more eloquent ways. this is just fast and dirty.